# sfdx cli throwing error "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory" after upgrading to v7

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

After upgrading to v7, all commands throwing the same error and then completing the actual command.

Output of `sfdx --version` command:

```
john@john-Latitude-E7440:~/workspace/Project_Folder$ sfdx --version
(node:29439) [EISDIR] Error Plugin: sfdx-cli: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/john/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.1.4-79f97a7df8'
module: @oclif/config@1.12.11
task: runHook init
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: /home/john/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.1.4-79f97a7df8
See more details with DEBUG=*
sfdx-cli/7.1.4-79f97a7df8 linux-x64 node-v10.15.3
```

Output of `sfdx plugins --core`:

```
john@john-Latitude-E7440:~/workspace/Project_Folder$ sfdx plugins --core
(node:29594) [EISDIR] Error Plugin: sfdx-cli: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/home/john/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.1.4-79f97a7df8'
module: @oclif/config@1.12.11
task: runHook init
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: /home/john/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.1.4-79f97a7df8
See more details with DEBUG=*
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.2.2 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 2.1.6 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.2 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.7.8 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.3.9 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.0.2 (core)
analytics 1.1.2 (core)
generator 1.1.0 (core)
mo-dx-plugin 0.1.10
salesforcedx 45.8.2 (core)
├─ force-language-services 45.9.0 (core)
└─ salesforce-alm 45.11.0 (core)

sfdx-cli 7.1.4 (core)
```

Commands are doing what it is supposed to do but throwing this error.

**EDIT**:

Output of command `la -la /home/john/.local/share/sfdx/client`:

```
john@john-Latitude-E7440:~/workspace/Project_Folder$ ls -la /home/john/.local/share/sfdx/client
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Mar 29 10:59 .
drwxrwxr-x   6 john john   4096 Mar 29 18:59 ..
drwxr-xr-x   5  998  995  4096 Mar 29 10:59 7.1.4-79f97a7df8
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 29 10:59 bin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 Mar 29 10:59 current -> ./7.1.4-79f97a7df8
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Mar 28 10:27 dist
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  1296 Mar 28 10:27 install
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1485 Mar 28 10:27 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x 623 root root 20480 Mar 28 10:27 node_modules
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    33 Mar 28 10:27 oclif.manifest.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  5944 Mar 28 10:27 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2363 Mar 28 10:27 README.md
```

Output of command `sfdx --version --dev-debug` in this link: http://pasted.co/a290ccf2

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: But commands still work for you? That is really odd. Usually that is a permission issue or ownership issue. What is the output of `ls -la /home/john/.local/share/sfdx/client` and `sfdx --version --dev-debug`?

Comment: @Amphro Updated question with the output of both commands. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the permission issues because you are probably running `sfdx` as your user but the sfdx dirs are owned by root. Did you install the CLI as root? Or may be you did a `sudo sfdx update`? Either way, the CLI shouldn't be ran as sudo. You should be able to fix this by changing the permissions of that folder to your user. Something like:

```
chown -R john /home/john/.local/share/sfdx
```

Comment: yes, I did `sudo sfdx update`. Its fixed now. Thanks.